Algorithm to show that CFGNotAll is recursively enumerable
The task is to create an algorithm that shows that the problem CFGNotAll is recursively enumarble. CFGNotAll is defined as: Given a context free grammar G in CNF over the alphabet {a,b} with Variables $ \{X_i\mid  i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is $L(G) \neq \{a,b\}$*. And recursively enumarble in the sense of: A problem $L$ is recursively enumarble if there exist a turing machine $M$ with two strings which recursively writes all yes instances of $L$ to it's second string. $M$ does not have an input and doesn't need to terminate.
My first rough idea was to use an like an index $k$, and then a for-loop with $i$ from 1...$k$ and then create grammars that can only produce a's up to the length of $i$, then b's than both. So that the amount of variables is equal to $i$. For a grammar that only creates the word $a^i$ would be created like this:
For $i$ in $1....k$ do: Create Rule $X_i \rightarrow aX_{i+1}$
With $X_1$ being the start variable.
For a grammar that can create a's and b's it would probably pretty similar:
For $i$ in $1....k$ do: Create Rule $X_i \rightarrow aX_{i+1} \mid bX_{i+1}$
But with this the algorithm will never create the grammar G with $L(G)=\{ab\}$ for example, which is a yes-instance.
I would love if anyone could give me a hint on how to go about this problem, thanks in advance.

Using a theorem about decidability of CFGs can be very useful here. This theorem states:
The following set is recursive:
A_CFG = {<G,s> | G is a CFG and s is a string which is drivable from G}
What we want to do is to proof the following set is recursively enumerabe:
CFGNotAll = {  | G is a CFG such that for any member of {a,b}* there is a derivation from G}
To proof this statement we need to provide an algorithm such that for given CFG say G, if G belongs to CFGNotAll, Then machine halts and gives 1 as output.
Given Grammer G:
Enumerate {a,b}*. Let
s0, s1, s2, ....
Be our enumeration.
For s(i), Check whether s(i) is drivable from G.
If it doesn't, halt and print 1.
Otherwise, Look for other counter example s(j) , j > i.
The algorithm described above is guaranteed that it will recognize members of CFGNotAll. It is easy to prove it.
Using this algorithm, You can easily provide an enumerator for CFGNotAll.
